# Get RDFNode from Jena ResultSet

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

How can I retrieve a Jena RDFNode from the ResultSet produced by a QueryExecution?  I am able to see the correct ResultSet after running the query but the result merely provides only the URI of the node, could anyone tell me what needs to be done in order for me to fetch the RDF node details. This would let me extract each property which I can later manipulate later. The work around I see is using a query that displays the properties of the instance rather than the instance itself.

Current Result:

```
http://assignment3.stdi.msmsuhail.ead/bpl.owl#Arsenal
```

Expected Result:

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://assignment3.stdi.msmsuhail.ead/bpl.owl#Arsenal">
    <bpl:hasStadiumLocation rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Holloway</bpl:hasStadiumLocation>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://assignment3.stdi.msmsuhail.ead/bpl.owl#Clubs"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual"/>
    <bpl:hasStadiumName rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Emirates Stadium</bpl:hasStadiumName>
    <bpl:hasPlayer rdf:resource="http://assignment3.stdi.msmsuhail.ead/bpl.owl#TheoWalcott"/>
    <bpl:hasPlayer rdf:resource="http://assignment3.stdi.msmsuhail.ead/bpl.owl#MikelArteta"/>
    <bpl:hasName rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Arsenal</bpl:hasName>
    <bpl:hasNumberSeats rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">60355</bpl:hasNumberSeats>
    <bpl:hasManager rdf:resource="http://assignment3.stdi.msmsuhail.ead/bpl.owl#ArseneWenger"/>
    <bpl:hasPlayer rdf:resource="http://assignment3.stdi.msmsuhail.ead/bpl.owl#AaronRamsey"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

SPARQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?clubs ?clubName 
WHERE {
    ?Club bpl:hasPlayer ?players.
    ?Club bpl:hasManager  ?managers.
    ?players bpl:hasClub ?clubs .
    ?players bpl:hasAge ?playerAge.
    ?players bpl:hasName ?playerName.
    ?players bpl:hasNationality ?playerNationality.
    ?players bpl:hasPlayingPosition ?playerPosition.
    ?players bpl:isRetired ?playerIsRetired.
    ?clubs bpl:hasName ?clubName.
    ?clubs bpl:hasNumberSeats ?clubSeats.
    ?clubs bpl:hasStadiumName ?clubStadiumName .
    ?clubs bpl:hasStadiumLocation ?clubStadiumLocation.
    ?managers bpl:hasAge ?managerAge.
    ?managers bpl:hasName ?managerName.
    ?managers bpl:hasNationality ?managerNationality.
    ?managers bpl:isManager ?isManager.
} 
ORDER BY ASC (?clubName)
```

Java Code:

```java
    while(resultSet!=null && resultSet.hasNext()){
                   QuerySolution querySolution = resultSet.nextSolution();
                   System.out.println(querySolution.get("clubs").toString());                              
    }
```

Comment: Are you running a local query or a remote query?  If you're running a remote query, then you will need to retrieve _all_ the triples in which you are interested (and you might be more interested in a CONSTRUCT query than a SELECT).  If you are running a local query, so that you have the model containing all the data at hand, then you can use that Model to retrieve the properties you are interested in once you have identified the resource or resources that you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Javadoc for [QuerySolution#get(String)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/QuerySolution.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) says that the return value *is* an RDFNode, so the value you are getting already is an RDFNode. If you are running a local query (i.e., if you have the model that the query is run against), then you can get property values using it, e.g.,

```java
RDFNode clubNode = querySolution.get( "club" );
Resource club = clubNode.asResource().inModel( model );
Statement stmt = club.getProperty( BPL.hasStadiumLocation );
System.out.println( stmt.getObject() ); // prints "Holloway"
```